# C# ExpressiveAnnotations how to real value in error message

Tags: c#

```
[RequiredIf("GoAbroad == true && NextCountry != 'Other' && NextCountry == Country",
    ErrorMessage = "If you plan to travel abroad, why visit the same country {NextCountry} twice?")]
public string ReasonForTravel { get; set; }
```

I would like to read `NextCountry` in `ErrorMessage` with `ExpressiveAnnotations`.

Link in github:
https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations

Is it possible? What is notation for reading value in ErrorMessage?

Comment: any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Functionality to be implemented in next version - initial commit [here](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/commit/0184852a5eea99b7317b895a3f5df4ad1ed9b138). For sure needs to be yet refactored, optimized and unit-tested. If you have any suggestions share it please.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for commit. I will wait for final release.

Comment: done in [2.6.2](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/releases/tag/v2.6.2)

Comment: make it as a comment that i can accept it